# HTML lexical Analyzer in c++ how to print results

Tags: c++, function, analyzer, lexical

I hope someone can help me again with this issue.  I am creating a HTML lexical analyzer in c++.  According to the teacher I am supposed to have 3 files.  one header and 2 main .cpp and it should be able to read a file
**This is my file try.txt**

```
<<<<<Hello there <H1 style=”BOLD”>header!!</H1> 
<<
<< =
```

**This is my header**

```
#ifndef tokens_h
#define tokens_h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

            enum tokens {TEXT, LANGLE = 60, RANGLE = 62, SLASH = 47, ID, EQ = 61, QSTRING = 34, OTHER, END};

/* TEXT    = 0
   LANGLE  = 60
   RANGLE  = 62
   SLASH   = 47
   ID      = 48
   EQ      = 61
   QSTRING = 34
   OTHER   = 36
   END     = 36

*/
            int getToken(std::istream *br, std::string a);

#endif
```

**This is my main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "tokens.h"


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //defineTokens();
    istream *br;
    ifstream infile;
    string output;
    int a;
    vector<int> count;
    int langle = 0;

            string line;
    if(argc == 1){
        while(cin.good() ){     //Get continous input
                br = &cin;

           getline(cin,line);
           getToken(br,line);
       }
    }
    else if(argc != 2){
        return 1;
    }else{
        infile.open(argv[1]);
        if( infile.is_open()){
            br = &infile;
            while(!infile.eof()){
            getline(infile,output);
        getToken(br,output);
            }
        }

        else{
            cout << argv[1] << "Can't Be Opened" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**and this is my tokens.cpp where I print the results**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include "tokens.h"



using namespace std;

void compar(int ch)
{
    vector<int> text;
    vector<int> langle;
    //string langle;
    vector<int> rangle;
    vector<int> slash;
    vector<int> id;
    vector<int> eq;
    vector<int> qstring;
    vector<int> other;
    map <string, int> result;
    int c=0;
    int d=0;
    int sum;
    string r;

    switch(ch){
        case 60:static int countlangle = 0;
                countlangle ++;
                result["LANGLE"]= countlangle; 
                cout << "LANGLE: " << result["LANGLE"] << " ";
                break;

        case 62:static int countrangle = 0;
                countrangle ++;
                result["RANGLE"]= countrangle; 
                cout << "RANGLE: " << result["RANGLE"] << " ";
                break;

        case 47:static int countslash = 0;
                countslash ++;
                result["SLASH"]= countslash; 
                cout << "SLASH: " << result["SLASH"] << " ";
                break;      

        case 61:static int counteq = 0;
                counteq ++;
                result["EQ"]= counteq; 
                cout << "EQ: " << result["EQ"] << " ";
                break;                                      

        case 34:static int countqstring = 0;
                countqstring ++;
                result["QSTRING"]= countqstring; 
                cout << "QSTRING: " << result["QSTRING"] << " ";
                break;  
    }


}
int getToken(istream *br, string a)
{

    int b;
    string d = "no";
    string f = "no";
    string r;
    vector<char> st;
    vector<string> trial;
    vector<int> countr;
    vector<int> countl;
    vector<char> quotes;
    string ans;
    int x=0;

    r = a;
    cout << a[27];


     int found;
            found = a.find('\"');
                        cout << found<<"XXxxxxxX";  


        for(int i = 0; i< a.length();i++){  //read entire string
        if(a[i] == '<'){
            // cout << LANGLE << " "; 
            d="yes";
            x +=1;
            countr.push_back(LANGLE);
            //cout << count.size();
            //cout << x;
            compar(LANGLE);
            b =LANGLE;

    //    return LANGLE;
        }
        else if(a[i]== '>' && d == "yes"){
            f = "yes";
            b = RANGLE;  //assing to the int variable the value from the enum header
            compar(RANGLE);

        }
        else if(a[i]== '/' && d == "yes"){
            compar(SLASH);

        }
        else if(a[i] == '=' && d == "yes"){
            compar(EQ);

        }
        else if(a[found] == '\"' && d == "yes"){

           //   for(int k =0;k < quotes.size();k++)
            //cout << r[found] <<"XXX"; 
            compar(QSTRING);

        }   

        }
    return 0;
}
```

The teacher want the program to print just the Final value of each case.  However, when I print I get this

```
LANGLE: 1 ID: 1 EQ: 1 ID: 2 RANGLE: 1 ID: 3 LANGLE: 2 SLASH: 1 RANGLE: 2 LANGLE: 3 ID: 4 RANGLE: 3 LANGLE: 4 LANGLE: 5 LANGLE: 6 ID: 5 RANGLE: 4 LANGLE: 7 LANGLE: 8 EQ: 2
```

Is there any way to get something like this?

```
LANGLE = 8
RANGLE = 4
EQ = 2
SLASH = 1
ID = 4
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `compar()` function multiple times, and **printing the current count of token in every call**.
This will give you every intermediate value of the count of each token.

Try to modify your `compar()` function to only increment the counts. DO NOT print values in it. Once the entire contents have been parsed, print the token value pairs by iterating over the map.

Comment: I tried to print after the switch but I get 11111122233345666788 .  Do I have to print somewhere else?  How do I do it?  thanks

Comment: Printing it outside the switch wont solve the issue, as it is till printed every time `compar()` is called. Print the values at the end of the loop that reads the strings, i.e, print just before the end of the main function. Understand that you need the count **after all strings have been parsed**. So wherever the entire parsing ends, print the list.

Comment: I just feel so dumb right now because I can't figure this out.  I think I will quit programming and move high into the mountains and stay there forever.  Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @electronyc I can understand your frustration, but I think you are not far from figuring it out. Lets run through your code once. What does the `main.cpp` do? It fetches the contents of the entire file and then passes them to the `tokens.cpp` or only line be line?

Comment: It reads line by line but I got a real boomer from the professor.  he said this by email "getToken should be doing the reading. the second argument to getToken is what is passed back OUT of getToken, not what is passed in".   I was getting each line and passing them through getToken.  I have no time to modify my program so I really give up.  I guess I have a long way to go before I become a good programmer.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @elctronyc This applies for all of us. If it were not so, we would not have had this huge community of people trying to help each other out :).
I understand that this was an assignment, but that is no reason to not do it right after the due date. Do get back to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for telling me to keep going.  The due day was postpone for friday and stayed up until 7 am this morning and I was able to solve most of the part that was bugging me.  I did not finish all for the lack of time and because I couldn't figure out how to do some reading but I will figure it out with time.  Thanks again